# Как перевернуть таблицу в DearPyGUI

Tags: python, dearpygui

Есть таблица dpg.table, нужно ее перевернуть, т.е первая строка = последняя, вторая = предпоследняя и т.д
В pandas я делал так

```
table = table.reindex(index=table.index[::-1])
```

как сделать тоже самое в dearpygui?